# How to replace character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to Replace a particular character on position 4 in sql Server , 
i know about replace or case when but my problem is that i just want to 4th position character replace ,

i am trying like

```
SELECT REPLACE(_NAME,0,1) AS exp FROM _EMPLOYEE
```

but it will not cheching 4th character

for example if `_name` contain `IMR002001` then it should be `IMR012001`

Answer (score 7):

Use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(_NAME, 4, 1, '@')
```

This replaces the substring starting at position 4 with length 1 with the string that is the fourth argument.  The string can be longer or shorter than the string being replaced.

For your example:

```
select stuff(_NAME, 4, 1, '1')
```